# Why doesn't my program print the right value after a for loop?

Tags: c, for-loop

I am trying the below C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i=10;
    int start=25;
    int end = 30;
    for(i = start; i < end; i++);
    {
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
}
```

I know there is a semicolon at the end of for loop which stops the for loop iterating more than once. But I get the output '30', instead of '25'.  Why am I getting this result? Variable `i` should retain its start value, right?

Comment: `i` start from `25` and inc for `5` times. Then will be `30`....

Comment: Thanks for all. everyone comments are really helpful.

Comment: This question actually asks "Why does a for loop count" (as expected). You might want to read the chapter about loops in your C book.

Comment: Why does this question have 8 upvotes?

Answer (score 23):

```
for(i = start; i < end; i++);
```

That code means that `i` is `25`. The loop continues while `i<30`.
Then after the loop, `i` will be, as you wrote, `30`.

Putting a semicolon at the end of loop does not stop the loop: it is executed.
In your case `{}` only open a different [scope](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_scope_rules.htm) inside the main function.

Answer (score 19):

The snippet

```
for(i = start; i < end; i++);
{
     printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

is equivalent to

```
for(i = start; i < end; i++);
printf("%d\n", i);
```

Expanding further

```
for(i = start; i < end;)
{
    i++;   // This statement will execute till i < 30
}
printf("%d\n", i);
```

The condition `i < end` will evaluate to `false` when `i` will be incremented to `30` by the execution of the statement `i++` inside the loop body.
Now, the statement `printf("%d\n", i);` will be executed and will print the value of `i` which is `30`.

Answer (score 16):

> I know there is a semicolon at the end of for loop which stops the for loop iterating more than once.

That is not exactly right: semicolon after `for` loop becomes *loop's empty body*. The loop iterates five times, incrementing `i` in each iteration. The statement in curly braces gets executed only when the loop is over.

At that point `i` becomes `30`, because that is your loop's *post-condition* (i.e. the condition that *must* be true in order for the loop to finish). That's what gets printed by the `printf`.

Answer (score 10):

```
for(i = start; i < end; i++);
```

This loop will iterate for `5` times , until `i` becomes equal to `end` i.e `30`. It will not stop after `1`st iteration .

Due to `;` the following `printf` is not part of loop body , but `;` doesn't mean that loop will iterate for `1` time . It will iterate til condition is `true` but loop's body does not contain anything other than `;`.

Answer (score 8):

Because of the colon your program is now equivalent to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        int i=10;
        int start=25;
        int end = 30;

        for(i = start; i < end; i++)
        {
                //do nothing
        }

        printf("%d\n", i);

}
```

Your loop moves `i` to `30` and then prints it.

Answer (score 2):

The code within the braces (below `for`) is not part of your for loop.
In other words your loop does not have a body due to the inclusion of the semicolon at the end of the `for` statement.